# Understanding proof that the formal power series ring in one variable is a PID

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading [A Term of Commutative Algebra](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/13Ed.pdf) by Altman and Kleiman. In example 3.11, they write the following:

> Let $k$ be a ring, and $A := k[[X]]$ the formal power series ring in
>   one variable. A **formal Laurent series** is a formal sum of the form
>   $\sum_{i=-m}^\infty X^i$ with $a_i\in k$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. These
>   series form a ring $k\{\{X\}\}$. Set $K:=k\{\{X\}\}$.
>
> Set $f:=\sum_{i=-m}^\infty a_iX^i$. If $a_{-m}\in k^\times$, then
>   $f\in K^\times$; indeed, $f=a_{-m}X^{-m}(1-g)$ where $g\in A$, and
>   $f\cdot a_{-m}^{-1}X^m(1+g+g^2+\cdots)=1$.
>
> Assume $k$ is a field. If $f\neq0$, then $f=X^{-m}u$ where $u\in A^\times$. Let $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ be a nonzero ideal. Suppose
>   $f\in\mathfrak{a}$. Then $X^{-m}\in\mathfrak{a}$. Let $n$ be the
>   smallest integer such that $X^n\in\mathfrak{a}$. Then $-m\geq n$. Set
>   $b:=X^{-m-n}u$. Then $b\in A$ and $f=bX^n$. Hence
>   $\mathfrak{a}=\langle X^n \rangle$. Thus $A$ is a PID.

Where I am lost is at the point where they say that $X^{-m}\in\mathfrak{a}$. Since $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$, and $A$ is the set of formal power series (not Laurent series), how can $X$ raised to a negative power be there?

Comment: $m$ is not necessarily positive. The assumption that $f \in \mathfrak{a}$ in fact implies that $m \le 0$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, I see. Thank you. I guess they just wrote it with a minus not to have to define $f$ again.

Comment: $-m$ is just a symbol,in fact,if $f\in \mathfrak{ a}$,then it just gives an expression of $f$ as $f=X^{-m}u$ with $-m\geqslant 0$ and $u\in A^{\times}$

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple: if $f=X^{-m}u\in\mathfrak a$, then $X^{-m}=fu^{-1}\in\mathfrak a$.

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear in my formulation, but I don't think this really answers my question. But I got an answer in the comment above. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @Student G: Note that, in my answer, I don't make any hypothesis as to the sign of $m$. The argument is purely formal (which is quite appropriate, given the subject!).

Comment: But $X^{n}\not\in k[[X]]$ when $n$ is negative? No?

Comment: No, it's only in $k((X))$.

Comment: Yes, and $\mathfrak{a}\subset A=k[[X]]$, so $X^n\not\in\mathfrak{a}$ for negative $n$.

Comment: You're absolutely right.